# Parse xml tag attributes using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I have one xml. Example XML is given below

```
<company sample="text">
<employee id="001" sex="M" age="20">Premshree Pillai</employee>
</company>
```

I need to get company attribute sample value

I am trying this method

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
var currLoanXml = '<company sample="text"><employee id="001" sex="M" age="20">Premshree Pillai</employee></company>';
var pic = $(currLoanXml).find('company').attr('sample');
alert(pic);
};
</script>
```

Its Shows Undefined in my alert box.

But i can also alert this child tag its working

```
var pic = $(currLoanXml).find('employee').attr('id');
alert(pic);
```

What is a problem. I need to get first tag attributes. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `filter()` instead of `find()` here because `company` is the root element, ie `currLoanXml` refers to the company element. `find` will look for decedent elements only

```
var currLoanXml = '<company sample="text"><employee id="001" sex="M" age="20">Premshree Pillai</employee></company>';
var pic = $(currLoanXml).filter('company').attr('sample');
alert(pic);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LhhHW/)

Comment: Hi @Arun P Johny..Instead of, I using javascript how can i get title from xml file ?

Answer (score 2):

You go too deep

```js
$(function() {
  var currLoanXml = '<company sample="text"><employee id="001" sex="M" age="20">Premshree Pillai</employee></company>';
  var sample = $(currLoanXml).attr('sample');
  console.log(sample);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```