# Mysql binary tree select query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have a accounts table. every account creation I am pushing treeRight id and treeLeft id into account_device_tree table.

Now I have more than 10M accounts under first parent account. when I select all the subaccouts it is taking more than a min to execute.

my query is given below

```
select * 
FROM
    accounts acc 
        JOIN
    account_device_tree ON acc.tree_id = account_device_tree.tree_id
WHERE
(acc.account_id = 1 OR (account_device_tree.tree_left >= 1 AND account_device_tree.tree_right <= 748534))
```

I need to optimize as much as possible.

schema of account_device_tree

```
CREATE TABLE `account_device_tree` (
  `tree_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tree_left` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tree_right` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tree_id`),
  KEY `tree_left` (`tree_left`),
  KEY `tree_right` (`tree_right`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=388173 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

accounts table Schema

```
 CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tree_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tree_id` (`tree_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `idx_parent_id` (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=389739 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: What indexes do you have if any? ad.account_id, account_user_device_tree.tree_left,  account_user_device_tree.tree_right should have indexes, as should your joined fields treeid unles already a PK

Comment: Also please confirm which DBMS you are using so other users can assist, you have declared both MySQL and Postgresql

Comment: accounts table tree_id is a index and account_user_device_tree table tree_left and tree_right colums are indexed

Comment: you need to generate a query execution plan when you execute the query, this will give you an idea where its hanging

Comment: i am using Mysql DB

Comment: @jimmy8ball how to generate please guide me

Comment: impossible to answer without tables structures and knowing the query plan.. i would suggest to rewite the query into using a `UNION ALL` instead of `OR` as it tends to optimize better assuming the correct indexes.

Comment: Sure, theres bags of information already available on the offical documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland added schema

Comment: *"And the index declaration for tree right and left?"* it's in the CREATE statement? @jimmy8ball, but this schema is incomplete as the topicstarter has forgotten about the accounts table.

Comment: Do you need `SELECT *`, or perhaps just `SELECT acc.*`?

Comment: @RickJames I want select account_device_tree.tree_left, account_device_tree.tree_right

Comment: Would you care to return and process [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18398647/295783) you abandoned?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to suggest something without table structures and query plan..
But rewritting the query into `UNION ALL` instead of using `OR` tends to optimize beter assuming the correct indexes are in the table.

```
select * 
FROM
    accounts acc 
        JOIN
    account_user_device_tree ON acc.tree_id = account_user_device_tree.tree_id
WHERE
  acc.account_id = 1 

UNION ALL

select * 
FROM
    accounts acc 
        JOIN
    account_user_device_tree ON acc.tree_id = account_user_device_tree.tree_id
WHERE
   account_user_device_tree.tree_left >= 1
 AND
  account_user_device_tree.tree_right <= 748534
```

Comment: `INDEX(tree_left, tree_right, tree_id)` and (presumably) `PRIMARY KEY(account_id)`?

Comment: But @NathanSrivi for a better answer (if you still need it) you should provide all table structures not just one.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have added account table schema. account_user_device_tree  table name I updated to account_device_tree

Comment: iám pretty sure you have manually changed/wrote the create table statements.. @NathanSrivi  as there are syntax errors all over, use `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` .. if need to edit make sure you [test](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) these `CREATE TABLE` statements.